# How to read code of trigger which was created with option WITH ENCRYPTION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to read code of trigger which was created with option WITH ENCRYPTION on remote server SSMS 2012?
Are there some tips and tricks?

Comment: The trigger was created with encryption so that the trigger code cannot be scripted and thus read anymore. I'm assuming you didn't create the trigger, correct?

Comment: @TT, yes this is not my trigger

Comment: @SMor, Thank you!